# string concatenation in Groovy seems inconvenient

Tags: groovy

My goal is to write this:

```
println "this should be 3: ($1+2)" //this is invalid groovy, it won't run
```

Yet this is valid in ruby. Is there a way I can put statements that will eval inside a string or must I use complete variables names? I am basically looking for the Ruby equivalent of:

```
puts "this shoud be 3: #{1+2}" #this is valid ruby
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you need

```
println "this should be 3: ${1+2}"
```

If the code being evaluated is a variable name or a GPath expression you can omit the curly braces, e.g.

```
def foo = "bar"
println "The value is $foo"
```

But if you want to be on the safe side, always put the code inside `${}`